# detect differences in a pair of image, one has lower bitrate and one has higher

Tags: tensorflow, neural-network, computer-vision

I have tried multi-scale ssim and psnr to detect whether there are any artifacts in a pair of images (one has higher bitrate and one has lower) but it is not really accurate.

Multi-scale ssim has too many false alarm and psnr could not detect there is a block if the block color is very similar to the background.

I want to use neural network on a pair of image (one is perfect and another one might or might not has block or line)to detect if there is any differences. I have tried image retraining of Tensorflow to categorize with block and without block but the accuracy is very low (50%). What method should I use to achieve higher accuracy?

I am thinking of feeding a pair of image at a time into neural network so it would know if there is something difference between two image, it should categorize it as with_error. But the problem is how do I feed a pair of image into the neural network (I can put one image at a time only) and how do I make it learn from each other in a pair of image. I saw people put two pictures horizontally and save it as one image. Can it detect like that?

Here's what I have done
https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/tensorflow-for-poets/#0

I used the code from the link above and replaced flower images with my images. I got two folder, one contains images with error and one without. The output of the code is a percentage of the class, the higher it is means it belongs to that class.

Example of a pair of image is:

[image: pair1]

[image: pair2]

Comment: Can you post some example image pairs?

Comment: yes I have posted it already

Comment: Why do you want to use a neural network? I think there are much easier ways.

Comment: Do you mean detecting images that has a white line in the middle? If not you need better/more example image pairs.

Comment: @ziggyjones I want to use some metrics like psnr, ms-ssim but the accuracy is pretty low that I don't think it reflects real human perception of quality. can you please suggest some ways?

Comment: @hkchengrex There are too many noises that I could not provide examples. Most of the noise that I encountered were a white /green line or block, macroblocking, brighter or darker, the video frame overlapped with previous frames.

Comment: Can't you just diff the images?

Comment: the bitrate of two image is different. There are noises in the image after I subtract them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use **[VMAF - Video Multi-Method Assessment Fusion](https://github.com/Netflix/vmaf)** from Netflix.

From the [Netflix Tech Blog (Medium)](https://medium.com/netflix-techblog/toward-a-practical-perceptual-video-quality-metric-653f208b9652):

> The basic rationale is that each elementary metric may have its own
> strengths and weaknesses with respect to the source content
> characteristics, type of artifacts, and degree of distortion. By
> ‘fusing’ elementary metrics into a final metric using a
> machine-learning algorithm — in our case, a Support Vector Machine
> (SVM) regressor — which assigns weights to each elementary metric, the
> final metric could preserve all the strengths of the individual
> metrics, and deliver a more accurate final score. The machine-learning
> model is trained and tested using the opinion scores obtained through
> a subjective experiment (in our case, the NFLX Video Dataset).

Therefore I think it fits your use case!

Hope it helps! Cheers

Comment: Glad that it helps! I wish that I saw this post earlier